# Identifying special folders of other users in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a file server which hosts users home drives. A subset of users have folder redirection so their folder names are all called 'My Documents' when viewed from explorer.

e.g.
\Auser
\Buser
...
\Kuser
\My Documents
\My Documents
\My Documents
\Nuser
....

Powershell seems to ignore the special 'My Documents' name and only list the real folder name underneath. The powershell properties of a normal folder and a redirected folder seem to be identical.

How can I use powershell to identify which folders have the special 'My Documents' name?

Comment: Your folder listing is nonsensical as it lists the same folder multiple times in the same location. Do you mean \Auser\My Documents, \Buser\My Documents, \Cuser\My Documents etc? Or are you trying to state that only certain users will have a My Documents folder listed in their share? If so, are those users defined by GPO or anything?

Comment: Each folder is the root level my documents. Usually you can't have identical child folders but with special folders explorer will show the label as "My Documents" multiple times. The folder is in fact a unique user name folder as shown in powershell and cmd prompt.

Comment: The folders only appear to be named "My Documents" because of the Desktop.ini file inside them.  The actual directory name is not "My Documents". You could check for a Desktop.ini file inside each user's profile, but it would up to you to read the file and determine if it used a display name of "My Documnents". Usually this is configured with `LocalizedResourceName=`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jscott for the clue about Desktop.ini

Here's how I got my listing, it shows each users folder name and if its 'normal' or one of the special redirected folders defined in the hash table ('Desktop' 'Documents'...)

```
$SpecialFolders = @{}
$SpecialFolders.Add("LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770","Documents")
$SpecialFolders.Add("LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769","Desktop")
$SpecialFolders.Add("LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21798","Downloads")
$SpecialFolders.Add("LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21779","Pictures")
$SpecialFolders.Add("PersonalizedName=","CustomName")


$folders = Get-ChildItem "\\someServer\homeDirs"

$folders | Select Name,@{l="Type";e={
    $desktopini = gci $_.fullname 'Desktop.ini' -Force
    if($desktopini){
        $desktopiniContents = Get-Content $desktopini.FullName
        $SpecialFolders.Keys | %{
            if($desktopiniContents -contains $_){$SpecialFolders.Item($_)}        
        }
    } else {
        "normal"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the special redirection folders that you would find in Windows 7 User directories you at least need to use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Force` which *Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files* as per [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx).

```
Get-ChildItem C:\users\SomeUser -Force |  Where-Object {$_.Attributes.ToString().Contains("ReparsePoint")}
```

This above would return aforementioned folders since they have the ReparsePoint attribute. More information on that can be located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365503(v=vs.85).aspx). Bare minimum you need `-Force` for what I think you are looking for.